# Problem trying to remove sub-query and use WHERE only to return certain rows

Tags: sql-server

I am extremely new to SQL queries. I am studying for Microsoft 70-461 and came to an example that I thought could be simplified, but my version is returning the wrong results, and I wanted to understand why.

This study guide show this query:

```
USE TSQL2012;
SELECT productid, productname, unitprice, P.supplierid
FROM Production.Products AS P
WHERE supplierid IN
    (SELECT supplier
     FROM Production.Suppliers
     WHERE country = N'Japan');
```

Which correctly returns 6 rows,
My query:

```
USE TSQL2012;
SELECT productid, productname, unitprice, P.supplierid
FROM Production.Products AS P, Production.Suppliers AS S
WHERE S.country = N'Japan':
```

Returns 231 rows, the production.products table only contains like 70 rows to begin with so I don't get it. Can somebody please tell me what I am overlooking. Thank you in advance.

[The sample database, "TSQL2012", can be downloaded here.](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/content/images/9780735666054/downloads/TK70461-20130524.zip)

Comment: Good luck in your exam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a predicate to describe matches between the two tables, you're simply listing all product / Japanese supplier combinations, regardless of whether or not the supplier is the right one for each product.

```
USE TSQL2012
GO

SELECT  
    p.productid ,
    p.productname ,
    p.unitprice ,
    p.supplierid
FROM    Production.Products p
JOIN  Production.Suppliers s ON p.supplierid = s.supplierid
WHERE   s.country = N'Japan';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the join condition in your statement, without this you are essentially getting all the products from the products table multiplied by how many suppliers in Japan there are (in your case 3).

To do the join correctly see the additional where clause I've added.

```
USE TSQL2012
GO

SELECT  p.productid ,
        p.productname ,
        p.unitprice ,
        p.supplierid
FROM    Production.Products p ,
        Production.Suppliers s
WHERE   s.country = N'Japan'
        AND p.supplierid = s.supplierid
```

Comment: Or use the more modern `JOIN ... ON` syntax. You're less likely to forget a join predicate that way.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: It returns the correct results, sure, but it uses ancient and ill-advised implicit join syntax. Explicit `INNER JOIN` is much more preferable in modern times.